# MOD_REWRITE: How to rewrite /something to /something.html?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

I tried using the following code but I don't see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(*)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `.` in your regular expression:

This:

```
RewriteRule ^(*)$ $1.html
```

needs to be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

You could also add this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
```

to prevent 500 errors when someone requests a page that doesn't exist and properly return a 404.